# C# WebBrowser Control can't handle "Umlaute" / special chars like üäö in path

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, special-characters, preview

I have a big problem with the C# WebBrowser Control.
To give you a sight of what im trying to do:

I have a application with a document section, where you can add all types of documents. Also there is a documentsearch where you can search for documents. If you select a document from the documentsearchlist it shows a preview if the document is a image.

Now I also want to add a preview for .pdf documents. I want to do this with the C# WebBrowser Control! I made some examples and discovered this "bug" of the WebBrowser Control.

Description of the bug:
I have a WebBrowser Control in my project and a .pdf file on my harddrive. Now I use webBrowser.Navigate("path of my pdf file") to display the .pdf file in my project. This works fine as long as there is no "Umlaut" / special char in the path or file! If there is a "Umlaut" / special char in the path, the WebBrowser Control throws a path not found exception.

The WebBrowser control somehow converts my filepath to a path which doesn't work. And I tried to convert, encode, decode etc... my filepath several times with several methods, but I allways end up with this error :(

Here is some sample code:

```
WebBrowser _webBrowser = wbSample;
string test = "file:///C:/test.pdf";
_webBrowser.Navigate(test);
```

This example above works just fine! Like you'd expect!

```
WebBrowser _webBrowser = wbSample;
string test = "file:///C:/täst.pdf";
_webBrowser.Navigate(test);
```

But this example above doesn't work at all! Just because there is a "ä" in the filename. The same happens if it is in the paht. But if I copy the path "file:///C:/täst.pdf" to internet explorer, it works. The error message looks like this:
[WebBrowser Control Error with path "file:///C:/täst.pdf"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SsyHs.png)

I really tried everything I can think of and need your help. Please give some inputs on what I can try to get it working. And has anybody had the same issue?

Comment: You need to [encode](https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+url+encode&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) the URL to make it valid.

Answer (score 1):

As @itsme mentioned, you need to use [HttpUtility.UrlEncode-Methode: (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/4fkewx0t(v=vs.110).aspx) like this:

```
WebBrowser _webBrowser = wbSample;
string test = "file:///C:/täst.pdf";
//_webBrowser.Navigate(test);
_webBrowser.Navigate(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(test));
```

Comment: Hi, first thank you for your answer! As said I tried several encode methods, and none of them works... For some reason I can't use HttpUtility that you mentioned, so I tried it with WebUtility.HtmlEncode but this gave the following error: "file:///C:/t&#228;st.pdf" was not found

Comment: @user2738829 You don't want HtmlEncode, you want UrlEncode. They're different encoding methods.

Comment: Thank you, I now managed to reference to the System.Web.dll. Now I excactly use the code of you above, but the webBrowser.Navigate method throws a "Not valid URI, the format of the URI could not be determined" exception...

Answer (score 0):

So I got something to work, but I still doesn't accomplish my requirements:

```
WebBrowser _webBrowser = wbSample;
string filename = "täst.pdf";
string basepath = "file:///C:/";
string encodedfilename= HttpUtility.UrlEncode(filename, Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1"));
string uri= basepath + encodedfilename;
_webBrowser.Navigate(uri);
```

So after the encoding + string operations, the uri looks like this: "file:///C:/t%e4st.pdf" and is correctly displayed by the webBrowser! So far so good ;)

The problem is, when the basepath also contains special chars like in this code example:

```
WebBrowser _webBrowser = wbSample;
string filename = "file:///C:/földer/täst.pdf";
string encodedfilename = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(filename, Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1"));
_webBrowser.Navigate(encodedfilename);
```

This one gives me a uri format exception, and the encoded filename looks like this: "file%3a%2f%2f%2fC%3a%2ff%f6lder%2ft%e4st.pdf"

I think I'm not allowed to encode the / of the path. Does anyone has a simple solution for this?